# How can i make a flex item grow to both ways

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to grow an item (.sub-container) to the both ways when I validate my form, top and bottom, but when the error mesage appear, it only grow to bottom and I'm here all day long and I already change everything in my code but it didn't grow the both ways, it just grew bottom, the ".container" is where everything are inside, pls someone know how to do it?

```
    .container{
        width: 80%;
        padding: 70px 0;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .sub-container{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-grow: 1;
            width: 50%;
    }
```

[before validate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Ofu.png)

[after validate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDd5C.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please update your question and provide a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with relevant code parts. i.e HTML code. thank you

Comment: Not sure what you mean by grow to top.  It can't go any higher than it already is on the page.

Comment: The error messages will cause everything to get pushed down.  That's just the way it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Flexible Box Layout Module, makes it easier to design flexible
> responsive layout structure without using float or positioning.

*Source @ https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp*

What you're trying to do as nothing to do with flexbox.

what you call "grow" is just default css behaviour. The only way to achieve what you want (Enlarging both height and width upon form submission) is realized by using javascript.